# saving gps data in sqlite and displaying on map?

Tags: android, sqlite, dictionary, gps, routes

I'd like know how I can get GPS data for a specific path(that is drawn on a map using long. and lat.) and save it in sqlite?
What I mean is that when the user enters the location and destination it displays the path on the map. I already did the map and drew the path but I want to save it in a database. [It is an android application].

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [at the table structure here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html). You can modify this to add your own data if needed.

Comment: it helps a bit thank you but I want for android sqlite and I want to save paths that I draw on the map in a database so that when the user enters the location and destination it will search for it in the database and display the path..any help?